# Use Drupal toolbar without drupal

Tags: javascript, css, drupal

I am trying to export js/css files of the drupal admin toolbar to use it somewhere else. is there an easy way of doing this ?

I need these two pieces shown [here](http://postimg.org/image/i6ss8ba0h/)

Comment: Have you tried copying the files?

Comment: I am trying to sort out hundred of linked js/css, but the main issue is security integration with drupal

Comment: Oh you want the physical drupal toolbar on a page that's not run by drupal? That's a lot more than just css/js. That's full PHP integration and stuff.

Comment: please see update. Do you think it is not practical ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way will be to just rebuild from scratch using that image as a template.

They may be some code snippets you can borrow, but most of the code will be too specific to Drupal to be easily reused.

Comment: That is what i did. trying to do what I want proved to be waste of time.